# Parsing pyparsing group of mixed character words

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to parse data fields from a Wikipedia infobox using pyparsing. To start with, the following code works:

```
from pyparsing import *

test_line = """{{Infobox company | name                = Exxon Mobil Corp | num_employees_year  = 2015 }}"""

data_group = Group(
    Suppress("|") +
    OneOrMore(White()).suppress() +
    Word(alphanums + printables)("key") +
    OneOrMore(White()).suppress() +
    Suppress("=") +
    OneOrMore(White()).suppress() +
    OneOrMore(Word(alphanums))("value") +
    ZeroOrMore(White()).suppress()
)

infobox_parser = (
    Literal("{{").suppress() +
    Word("Infobox") +
    White().suppress() +
    Word("company") +
    OneOrMore(White()).suppress() +
    OneOrMore(data_group)("values") +
    Literal("}}").suppress()
)

print(infobox_parser.parseString(test_line))
```

Which produces result:

```
['Infobox', 'company', ['name', 'Exxon', 'Mobil', 'Corp'], ['num_employees_year', '2015']]
```

The problem is when I change the test string to

```
test_line = """{{Infobox company | name                = Exxon Mobil Corp. | num_employees_year  = 2015 }}"""
```

It's failing because I introduced '.' as part of 'Corp.'. I thought I could fix this by changing the Group object to

```
data_group = Group(
    Suppress("|") +
    OneOrMore(White()).suppress() +
    Word(alphanums + printables)("key") +
    OneOrMore(White()).suppress() +
    Suppress("=") +
    OneOrMore(White()).suppress() +
    OneOrMore(Word(alphanums + printables))("value") +
    ZeroOrMore(White()).suppress()
)
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "}}" (at char 91), (line:1, col:92)
```

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a couple of things. Most significantly, pyparsing does not do the same kind of backtracking the way regex does. That is, something like this won't work:

```
data = '{' + OneOrMore(Word(printables))("data") + '}'
print(data.parseString('{ this is some data }'))
```

Why? Because the terminating '}' *also* matches as a `Word(printables)`, so the `OneOrMore` will just keep going until the end, and then fail because there is no terminating '}' to be found after reading data.

Up until recently, the solution was to include a guard inside the `OneOrMore` expression, a negative lookahed saying in effect "I want Word(printables), but first check if it's a '}' - I don't want that", and that looks like this:

```
data = '{' + OneOrMore(~Literal('}') + Word(printables))("data") + '}'
```

But this was so common, that I recently added an optional `stopOn` argument to `ZeroOrMore` and `OneOrMore`:

```
data = '{' + OneOrMore(Word(printables), stopOn=Literal('}'))("data") + '}'
```

In your case, where each data_group parses a `key=value` pair, your value was fine when you only parsed `OneOrMore(Word(alphanums))`. But once you changed it to `OneOrMore(Word(alphanums+printables))`, your repetition term would greedily match the next '|' or the terminating '}}', and fail just like the example above.

A couple of other items:

- pyparsing will skip whitespace for you. All those White() elements are completely unnecessary.
- In a couple of places you use Word incorrectly, as in `Word("Infobox")`. In your limited example, this matches ok, but remember that Word is defined with the set of characters that you will want to match as a word group, so `Word("Infobox")` will match not only "Infobox", but also any other word made up of the letters 'I', 'n', 'f', 'o', 'b', and/or 'x', such as "Inbox", "IbIx", "xoxoxox", etc. In this case, the pyparsing class you want would be `Literal` or `Keyword`.
- Stepping back, it looks like your data_groups are `key=value` pairs, with delimiting '|'s. I would suggest using `delimitedList` for this.
- Finally, use `dump()` to output your parsed data, it will help visualize the structure and results names.

With these changes, your code looks like:

```
data_group = Group(
    Word(alphas, alphanums+'_')("key") +
    Suppress("=") +
    originalTextFor(OneOrMore(Word(printables), stopOn=Literal('|') | '}}'))("value") 
)

infobox_parser = (
    Literal("{{").suppress() +
    Keyword("Infobox") +
    Keyword("company") + '|' + 
    Group(delimitedList(data_group, '|'))("values") +
    Literal("}}").suppress()
)

print(infobox_parser.parseString(test_line).dump())
```

Giving:

```
['Infobox', 'company', '|', [['name', 'Exxon Mobil Corp.'], ['num_employees_year', '2015']]]
- values: [['name', 'Exxon Mobil Corp.'], ['num_employees_year', '2015']]
  [0]:
    ['name', 'Exxon Mobil Corp.']
    - key: name
    - value: Exxon Mobil Corp.
  [1]:
    ['num_employees_year', '2015']
    - key: num_employees_year
    - value: 2015
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide such a detailed answer.